# Worklight app ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

my worklight hybrid app suddenly stopped working. I get stuck at white screen on launch.
Logcat shows this error:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin

I have tried to revert back any small changes I did and still no luck. I have looked at everything I can from application code point. Has anyone faced similar challenges?

Comment: i have same problem and resolved it, look my answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434840/missing-wlinitializationplugin-when-app-is-started-worklight-6-2]

Answer (score 0):

I think that deleting the **android\native** folder will help.
Deleting the native folder allows Worklight Studio to re-create everything.

If you've written custom classes and/or stored any resources, first back them up and then delete the native folder, followed by re-building the application in Worklight Studio. Then, run it in the device again. Hopefully will work.