# Missing WLInitializationPlugin when app is started worklight 6.2

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, ibm-mobilefirst

i've made ant tasks for build and deploy my project.
The ant tasks are proper configured, but when the application is downloaded from the appcenter or installed from the generated apk from jenkins it throws some classNotFoundExceptions when getting started:

```
02-10 16:10:54.860: W/System.err(7584): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLInitializationPlugin

02-10 16:10:55.640: W/System.err(7584): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WLApp
```

If i run the application from eclipse it works. I really don't know what is the difference between jenkins and eclipse building the project...

Environments:
worklight 6.2
android mobile platform

Comment: Have you made sure to take the ant task files from the server installation folder (they are extracted to there)? it could be they are not up-to-date.

Comment: @IdanAdar Yes the ant task files are up-to-date, i took them from /opt/IBM/Worklight/WorklightServer this is for worklight 6.2

Answer (score 1):

@IdanAdar I fix this as my **uicandroid.jar** and **worklight-android.jar** was old version from 6.1, so i copy it from 6.2 into native/libs folder and application is working as normal when is build from jenkins